# Image recognition to read 7segment Display

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, ocr, emgucv

I am implementing SURF to detect Digits inside a seven segment display using some template. But it is not working fine. Is there any way that can be slow but more effective. I am using Emgu Wrapper for OpenCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you don't use SURF and instead look into using tesserect for character recognition.

SURF is really good for recognising patterns such as logo's and images, but  for characters tesserect will not only produce better results, it's easier to implement!

You can create your own custom fonts to look for if the digits you are trying to read are non-standard.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqvvXJXuRYY&list=UUxAnMtjN08ryThpgYTBmILg

Try following this tutorial, its really helpful for getting started with OCR.

It's in VB but it won't be hard to write in C# once you have got the logic down.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tesserect worked fine for cleaner Image, But if I have "Dots" in images or some other small noise, Tesserect reads an extra character. Can you suggest a way to remove noise outside the character area??

Comment: sorry if this is abit late, there are several ways you can remove noise, look into either using a mixture of dilate/erosion to clean up small bits of noise.

You can also use the canny edge detector, there will be two values you pass into the detector when you use it, look up what these values do, and with a bit of playing around you should be able to find a setting that will pick out your characters but ignore smaller edges